# Mips assembly language on MARS

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I'm trying to create a program that will take a FP number (5.2) and output in increments of 1.0 until the highest value (20.2) is reached.

So the smallest value is 5.2 and the biggest is 20.2 there should be a loop.

The output should be:

5.2 6.2 7.2 and so on until 20.2

Answer (score -1):

Try this code :

```
    .data
spaces: .asciiz " "

fp1: .double 5.2
fp2: .double 20.2
fp3: .double 1.0


.text
main:
  
  l.d $f0,fp1   # $f0 register contains 5.2
  l.d $f2,fp2    # $f2 register contains 20.2
  l.d $f4,fp3     # $f4 register contains 1.0
  loop:
    li $v0, 3
        mov.d $f12,$f0
    syscall                 # syscall print floating point number
    
    li $v0 , 4 
        la $a0 , spaces
        syscall                   # syscall print space
         
    c.eq.d   $f0,$f2       # if $f0 == $f2 jump to EXIT
    bc1t EXIT
    add.d $f0,$f0,$f4      # else $f0 = $f0+$f4
  j loop
  
EXIT:        
  

  li $a0, 0
  li $v0, 17              #exit
  syscall
```

Comment: thanks that is what I was looking for. Do you also know how to read the user input, then store it and branch accordingly. For example, the prompt message is "select the correct answer?"

if the user entered "a" - go to destination 1 if the user entered "b" - go to destination 2 and if the user entered "c" - go to destination 3

so the only three possible answers are a b or c and it should branch accordingly to the next segment of code.